# Can I use Facebook Like button to make a choice buttons?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I would like to use Like button and Dislike button in my web and my mobile app with a little bar showing the proportion of each compared in 100% (like in youtube video). The user can only choose one of these. Can I achieve that using Facebook like button? or I need to make my own system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create your own system for that, the Like Button can only show "Like" or "Recommend" and is not customizable like that.